# Maximum size of a url encoded post request parameter

Tags: http, post, browser, parameters, size

For a backend application i have to transmit encrypted information with post capable for modern browsers.

Is the size of a single post parameter conform to the maximum url length or there are restrictions?

Refer to: [enter what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)[What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

Is the size browser independent i.e. defined in the http protocol?